# React Native How to Display Live Stream Video

Tags: react-native, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to display a live stream video on my app. Currently, I am using WebView to try to display the video using an embedded YouTube url. However, I want the mobile app to look like the first screen shot, but instead, I currently have the second screen shot.

```
<WebView
                style={{flex:1}}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/hHW1oY26kxQ?autoplay=0&fs=0&controls=1'}}/>
```

[Screenshot of livestream video on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBYoO.jpg) [Screenshot of livestream video on mobile (android)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0UAv.png)

More specifically, I would like to have the "Live" control and the settings control to at least change the quality and also the ability to skip ahead or go back 10 seconds, which the mobile app does have with current embed link.

I also tried using YouTube component, but that doesn't work for me since using control = 1 only displays the "Live" icon for live stream videos. What would be the best way to approach this? Thanks.